# Print function calls with a variable delay / Python

Tags: python, console, debugging

The question is, how can I configure the Python debugger to show me in the console what functions are being called?

In order not to see everything flash by, a delay between the function calls would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alternative [pydb](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/pydb/) debugger. You can invoke it with `pydb --fntrace --batch <scriptname>` to get a function trace.

As for the "flashing-by", use the usual tools like Ctrl-S/Ctrl-Q on an ANSI terminal, or redirect to a file.

Comment: I think this debugger can do the job that pdb can not! I found a nice tutorial on it at showmedo.com/videotutorials/… . See the "set linetrace delay 0.35" functionality in the middle of it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to monitor when a few particular functions are being called, 
you could use this decorator:

```
import functools
def trace(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*arg,**kw):
        '''This decorator shows how the function was called'''
        arg_str=','.join(['%r'%a for a in arg]+['%s=%s'%(key,kw[key]) for key in kw])
        print "%s(%s)" % (f.__name__, arg_str)
        return f(*arg, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

You would use it like this:

```
@trace          # <--- decorator your functions with the @trace decorator
def foo(x,y):
    # do stuff
```

When you run your program, every time foo(x,y) is called, you'll see the
function call with the value of its arguments in the console:

```
foo(y=(0, 1, 2),x=(0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Interesting functionality. In what versions of Python can you do this?

Comment: Decorators were introduced in 2.4, and functools was introduced in 2.5. There is an alternative way to write the trace decorator which does not rely on functools: See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator#a-trace-decorator